# Não estou conseguindo fazer o load adequadamente

Tags: jquery

O sistema faz o LOAD, mas quando clico uma segunda vez em qualquer link o mesmo duplica o link e se clicar de novo ele quadruplica e assim por diante e o botão sair só funciona na primeira página que fez load. Alguém sabe que caminho posso tomar?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#menu a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var right = $(".right");
        right.append("<div id='pagina'></div>");
        $("#pagina").load(href);
        $("#pagina").attr("id","sair");
    });

    //Fechar a janela com o JQUERY
    $("#botaoSair").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#sair').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: O que esse botão sair faz? Você pode inserir também a div que recebe isso e o botão sair?

Comment: O botão sair remove a DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema e aprimorar este código.

Compartilhando:

```
arrayJanela = [];//Variavel global
localStorage.setItem("zIndex", 3);//Set do primeiro zIndex

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#menu a").click(function(e)// Clica em alguma opção do menu
    {
        e.preventDefault(); // Previne para ocorrer apenas este evento no menu a
        var href = $( this ).attr('href'); // Colocar o link na variavel href
        var existe = false; // Defino que não existe hehe

        for (i = 0; i < arrayJanela.length; i++){ // Vejo todo o conteudo de arrayJanela
            if (arrayJanela[i]==href){ // Verifico se o link clicado existe no array
                existe = true; // Descobriu aqui que existe...
            }
        }

        if (existe){ // se existe
            var zIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("zIndex"));
            zIndex = zIndex + 1;
            localStorage.setItem("zIndex", zIndex);
            var split = href.split('.');
            split[0] = "#"+split[0];
            $(split[0]).find(".zIndex").css('zIndex',zIndex);
        }else{ // se não existe
            arrayJanela.push(href); // Inclui link no array
            $("#containerJanelas").prepend("<div id='janela' class='sair'></div>"); // Cria uma div chamada  janela
            $("#janela").load(href, function()//Ocorre o load do link na Janela
            {
                var zIndex = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("zIndex"));
                zIndex = zIndex + 1;
                $('#janela').find(".zIndex").css('zIndex',zIndex);
                localStorage.setItem("zIndex", zIndex);
                var split = href.split('.');
                $("#janela").attr("id",split[0]); // Muda o nome da nova página para os próximos loads não duplicarem
            });
        }

    });
});
```